# What can I do to prevent Android Studio from automatically clearing my log

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I've got an activity that when it launches, it crashes but it leaves no trace of what went wrong in the console. I can see a very brief moment of red text before its cleared. The dropdown which shows the currently debugged app quickly switches from my app to "no debuggable applications" and back in the blink of an eye.

Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to disable the ADB integration:

Tools -> Android -> Enable ADB integration

There should be no icon before this menu item.

Your LogCat now keeps the log output after your application closes or the application crashes.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the Android Studio console and find the drop down list which states 'Show only selected application'. Change it to 'No Filters' to see **all** log output from the Android device. You'll have to navigate to find your crash, but your class names, etc. and log tags will all be there so it won't be too difficult.

[image: No filters]

Comment: Easiest solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can store you log into a file. Go to your terminal and type `adb logcat > logfile.txt`

(If your have not done it before you will need to add the directory `platform-tools` of your sdk to your path. See this link http://www.troubleshooters.com/linux/prepostpath.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a a good solution to this behavior, but there are some alternative strategies for getting the logcat to display.

First, the logcat is actually available in two places in Android Studio. The first is the logcat tab in the debug pane, which is the one that gives me the most trouble. The second is the logcat tab in the Android pane, which usually works a little better. If there is nothing there either, typically setting the filter to "no filter" and log level to "error" will get me where I want to be.

Second, you can always run logcat from a command prompt. The output won't be as pretty or as readily filterable, but you can write it to a text file and search in there. I generally use `adb logcat -v time > logcat.txt`to include the timestamps and write the log to a text file.